# PHP - compare multiple values and form them in specific order

Tags: php, compare

So, I have an array:

```
$n=array('175','102','99','10','250','302');
```

I want to compare each value with each another and to echo four (or five) statuses for them (1 - lowest, 2 - low, 3 - mid, 4 - highest). How do I do that with PHP?

I know a way where I can echo only three statuses (low, mid, high):

```
$status=array();
$min_n=min($n);
$max_n=max($n);

for($i=0;$i<count($n);$i++){
    if($n[$i]==$min_n){
        $status[$i]='1';
    }elseif($n[$i]==$max_n){
        $status[$i]='3';
    }else{
        $status[$i]='2';
    }

    echo $n[$i].' status - '.$status[$i].'<br />';
}
```

echo will be:

```
175 status - 2
102 status - 2
99 status - 2
10 status - 1
250 status - 2
302 status - 3
```

But if I need four (or five) statuses?

Comment: How do you choose your statuses ?

Comment: What is the significance of each status?

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to define the regions? One way would be to take the difference between min and max, and divide it by the number of ranges.

```
$n=array('175','102','99','10','250','302');

$num_ranges = 5;

$status=array();
$min_n=min($n);
$max_n=max($n);

$step = ($max_n + 1 - $min_n)  / $ranges;

for($i=0;$i<count($n);$i++){

    $status[$i] = ceil(($n[$i] + 1 - $min_n ) / $step);
    echo $n[$i].' status - '.$status[$i]."\n";
}
```

Comment: That works, but...
The lowest value must have '1' status and highest must have '5' status, other values should be between.

In your way 250 and 302 has status '5'...